# How to get instance usage data for billing from Ceilometer client?

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I am creating billing module for openstack. I am trying to get instances running for particular tenant during last 30 days.

I tried using ceilometer client for accessing this.

I tried `client.samples("instance").list()`. However, it gives me guaged sample data. I want data for particular tenant and should have a start and end time.

How can I access it using ceilometer client?

Comment: Have you created that? I'm looking for a billing module to use in a public cloud. ```CloudKitty``` hasn't get completed yet.